# how to change datetime format from input using dataTables?

Tags: laravel, datetime, datatables, formatting

I followed all the tutorials from this link to create a date range filter and it worked but when I tried the results of the input it came out in an incorrect format, https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html
[image]

my data table record which was originally of type timestamps, I changed the format using carbon to Y-m-d, which I asked how to change this part of the format

```
minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
     format: 'YYYY Do MMMM'
 });
 maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
     format: 'YYYY Do MMMM'
 });
```

the table view

[image]

Comment: i already change the format to YYYY-MM-DD but the result still no matching data, is the problem come from type data record or carbon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var date = new Date( data[4] );
```

It should be :

```
var date = new Date( data[0] );
```